# Not able to fetch recipients from a text file send-mailMessage Powershell

Tags: email, powershell

This is ridiculous.

I am trying to send mail in powershell using the below command

```
$users= get-content "somepath/sometxt.txt"
Send-MailMessage -To $users -from $fromemail -SmtpServer $smtp
```

The sometxt.txt contains recipients as below :-

[image]

The above code works smoothly when I run on one computer. It takes the users from the sometxt.txt file and sends the mail.

But when I ran the same code on another computer.
It said

> parameter -to with aruguement $users is empty or null.

I don't have a screenshot of the error as it is on my office network.
Crazy part being, that when I write host $users just before the sendmail command it gives me the names confirming that it is not null/empty as below:-

```
$users= get-content "somepath/sometxt.txt"
write-host $users
Send-MailMessage -To $users -from $fromemail -SmtpServer $smtp
```

Result:-

> user1@domain1.com user2@domain2.com
>  send-mailmessage falied as -to
>   parameter with $users aruguement is null or empty

How can this be null or empty if it is printing the contents of the file ??
Could anyone help figure out why this is happening . Also let me know an alternative to fix this and send the mail out.

Comment: Well if the computer it works on is not on the same network as the one it did not work on, it is obviously related to the network permissioning and security in some way. Does that computer have access to the folder and file? Does it allow you access to smtp? I'd start looking there.

Comment: yes it has . you see, it is printing the contents of the $users vairable on both computers as it is. No difference there. the only thing being that send-mailmessage says it empty on computer and runs fine on another. No issues with permissions.Smtp or any other error would have it's own error message .no problems there . it's just about $users variable showing as empty whereas it is not :(

Comment: `$users = Get-Content "somepath/sometxt.txt" | Where-Object { $_.Trim() -ne '' }` would  skip blank lines. HTH.

Comment: More information is required.  For example: What is SomePath?  Local path, network path, mapped network drive?  Running under a single user account on both workstations?  Different user accounts?  We test file access using LS, Dir or `Get-ChildItem -path "somepath"`